# Table cell contents don't vertical align after adding a left floated <ul>

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

http://jsfiddle.net/LEARy/

In my table cell I've got an unordered list floated to the left, after that I have some text within the same cell. So I've added the `vertical-align:middle` property... still no help. The text not in the list did not align vertically. I've tried modifying `line-height` property to match the cell's height, nothing happened.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css

> li {display:inline;}
>   http://jsfiddle.net/LEARy/3/

Comment: Thanks, but the list becomes horizontal? Or is that just jsFiddle's own html rendering error?

Comment: This is not what you wanted ? ... it the question is not very clear... so what is the expected result look like?

Comment: I want every object within the cell to be centered, vertically aligned. In my jsfiddle example, the "text" was a little bit off the middle.

Comment: @stockoverflow I'm really not understanding what you're wanting here. Could you draw us a picture or something?

Comment: Nevermind, I've fixed it by wrapping td contents within a div.